# Should I Install Windows 2003 Server Debugging Symbols in a Production Environment?

Tags: windows-server-2003, debugging

I have a software vendor that has requested that we install the Windows debugging symbols and the desktop heap monitor in our production environment.  The vendor is trying to determine if we are experiencing desktop heap exhaustion as the root cause of some COM+ issues.  Is there any risk or harm in installing these items on production servers?  I don't believe in debugging objects on a production system but I also don't want to overreact.  I appreciate everyone's opinion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't speak for the debug symbols first-hand, but there shouldn't be any problem running the DHMon.

The problem with running debug code on production machines is a performance hit. If you're still running the same EXEs from the vendor, and just pointing WinDbg to debug symbols, I don't think this will affect your performance at all.